# Angular2 "Getting Started" deployment with SystemJS

Tags: gulp, angular, systemjs

Kind of new to this whole SystemJS thing so I might be totally gleaming over the important parts in it's docs.  I am pretty familiar with bundling things using Browserify but this whole SystemJS has me scratching my head when it comes to deployment.  No pun intended because I am loving SystemJS otherwise.

Given the following from with the config file having the same config from the Angular2 5 minute quickstart:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="app.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

And the following from my Gulpfile using SystemJS Builder:

```
gulp.task('system-builder', function (cb) {
    var builder = new Builder('./production/public/', './production/public/app.config.js');
    fs.copy('./client/node_modules', './production/public/node_modules', function(err) {
        builder.bundle('./production/public/js/app/app.boot.js', './production/public/js/app/app.js')
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Build complete');
            cb();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

I now have a single app.js file.  Going back to the HTML file how do I use the application code in a bundled state? Because I get an `angular2-polyfills.js:322 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error when making the following update. Note that I have replaced app.config.js with /js/app/app.js:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="/js/app/app.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('/js/app/app.boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I have a seen a million and one hits on just using JSPM but I want to know how SystemJS natively handles this before make decisions on using more libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured this out.

Basically, you shouldn't need to do anything to the html file and can simply stay as is.

However, I needed to make SystemJS Builder self executing by using `build.buildStatic` instead of `build.bundle`

So ... the following works:

JS

```
gulp.task('system-builder', function (cb) {
    var builder = new Builder('./production/public/', './production/public/app.config.js');
    fs.copy('./client/node_modules', './production/public/node_modules', function(err) {
        builder.buildStatic('./production/public/js/app/app.boot.js', './production/public/js/app/app.js')
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Build complete');
            cb();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML(just leave as it is in dev mode)

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="app.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Mitchell, just 2 questions regarding your code; 1) shouldn´t you remove the import for app.config.js in your HTML and use app.js instead?
2) regarding the node_modules imports in your HTML, did you include those folders/files in your deploy folder? or with the bundle should be enough?

Comment: Hi @david, Yeah, this post was in the beta days and some things have changed now that's it's in RC4.  As I haven't had a chance to refresh myself lately I'd imagine your first question may or may not be applicable any more.  As far as you second question you do have to include those node_modules in your build directory but I have been aggregating them into a single libs.js using gulp.